# Possibilities to deploy a Spring-Boot app and a Pentaho Server?

Tags: database, heroku, spring-boot, deployment, pentaho

I have a Spring Boot app running for filling a MySQL database with data I want to analyze with OLAP. I chose Pentaho Data Integration, Schema Workbench and Business Intelligence Server (CE versions) to create my data warehouse. In the ETL process I just fill my data warehouse with the data I generated with my Spring Boot app. In the BI-Server I use the Saiku plugin to make all the OLAP operations and it all works quite nicely.

However I want to make all of that public.
Where is it possible to deploy my app with a database (preferably MySQL) and the BI-Server?

I've looked into Heroku and it seems to use PostgreSQL databases and I haven't found out about a possibility to deploy my BI-Server...  Or should I move away from Pentaho and use other solutions to make OLAP on my data warehouse?

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

You`d better use some cloud service like https://www.digitalocean.com/ or amazon. For your own linux server. At this server you can install BI server and Mysql.